# Retrieving a string that include single quotes: the quotes are not printed

Tags: mysql, html

I'm getting the value of a field from a mysql database. The value has single quotes in both sides like this: 'foo'.

When I retrieve the data using a PHP method from the html template, I get this code:

```
&#039;foo&#039;
```

but I want it shows just 'foo' (with the quotes).

Any idea?

Javier

Comment: at least show the code you use for retrieving the code

Comment: probably the string you saved on the database is htmlentities escaped

Answer (score 1):

`&#039;` is the ASCII code for `apostrophe-quote`.

If using PHP, use `html_entity_decode()` around the data being displayed from the database.

i.e. echo html_entity_decode($database_field_data);

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace.

```
echo str_replace("&#039;" , "'" , $data['string']);
```